# Flutter How to Build APK with Plugin Lib?

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I am using a lib like this,

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  image_picker: ^0.6.7+4
```

`app-release.apk`(file size 16M) does not work,
but `app-debug.apk`(49M) can work fine.

How can fix this problem?

Comment: have you tried to run "flutter build apk"

Comment: You can provide the gradle files to show more information

Comment: you need to add permissions in the manifest otherwise provide more information

Comment: #Fri Jun 23 08:50:38 CEST 2017
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7-all.zip

Comment: include ':app'

def localPropertiesFile = new File(rootProject.projectDir, "local.properties")
def properties = new Properties()

assert localPropertiesFile.exists()
localPropertiesFile.withReader("UTF-8") { reader -> properties.load(reader) }

def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
apply from: "$flutterSdkPath/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/app_plugin_loader.gradle"

Comment: buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

dependencies {
}